# How can I create code that will show prime numbers correctly in Python?

Tags: python

A prime number is a number that is only evenly divisible by itself and 1.
For example, the number 5 is prime because it can only be evenly divided by 1
and 5. The number 6, however, is not prime because it can be divided evenly
by 2 and 3.

Write a Boolean function named is_prime which takes an integer as an argument
and returns true if the argument is a prime number, or false otherwise. Use
the function in a program that prompts the user to enter a number and then
prints whether the number is prime.

This is the PYTHON code I have put in, but it tells me that it is wrong. I've tried but can't get it.

```
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num,"is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
        break
    else:
        print(num,"is a prime number")
    else:
        print(num,"is not a prime number")
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it.  `break` in wrong place and can't have (and don't want/need) two `else` clauses:

```
if num > 1:
    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num % i) == 0:
            print(num,"is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
            break
    else:
        print(num,"is a prime number")
```

Comment: also, the `else` statement here doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The `else` makes sense here but this should be modified to print that 2 is a prime number.

Comment: @AlexWalczak - Did you try my code?  It does print that 2 is a prime number

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort out the two else statements, and also change the algorithm so that it only prints `num` is a prime number if all the iterations of the for loop fail

```py
if num < 2: # catch 1 and anything less than zero
    print(num, "is not a prime number")
else:
    prime = True
    for i in range(2, num):
        if num%i == 0:
            print(num, "is not a prime number")
            print(i,"times",num//i,"is",num)
            prime = False
            break
    if prime:
        print(num,"is a prime number")
```

I would put this in an isPrime function. You only need to check factors up to the square root of the number.

Edit: I see in your question you mentioned this, you just need to modify this code to return `True` or `False`

```py
def isPrime(num):
    if num < 2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
    return True
```

Output

```
0 is not a prime number

1 is not a prime number

2 is a prime number

3 is a prime number

4 is not a prime number
2 times 2 is 4

5 is a prime number

6 is not a prime number
2 times 3 is 6

7 is a prime number

8 is not a prime number
2 times 4 is 8

9 is not a prime number
3 times 3 is 9
```

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to develop a quick but accurate `is_prime` function in Python. Here it is:

```
from math import sqrt # you can just import math, but I only use sqrt
def is_prime(n):
    if n<0:
        n*=-1
    if n<2:
        return False
    for i in range(2,int(sqrt(n))+1): # remember to fix sqrt to math.sqrt if you changed the
        if n%i==0:                    # import to import math instead of from math import sqrt
            return False
    return True
```

Explanation:
If x is prime then -x is prime. So I just make the number positive with

```
if n<0:
    n*=-1
```

0 is composite (it has the factors 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) and 1 is neither, and neither of those are prime, and since n>-1 (because it was absolute valued) the condition n<2 will suffice.

```
if n<2:
    return False
```

After that, I loop from 2 to `int(math.sqrt(n))+1`. That's just convert `math.sqrt(n)` into an int, and then add 1. The reason for math.sqrt is that n can only have factors until its square root (and also itself).  The +1 is for keeping the range in bounds if the `int()` made it less than it was before.

```
for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(n))+1):
    if n%i==0:
        return False
```

In the loop, I check if i (the loop counter) is divisible into n.  If it is, that means n has a factor that isn't 1 (it started from 2) or itself (it ends at the square root of itself, and 1 is not an exception because that was fixed with the if n<2 condition). At that point, it returns False.

If n gets through all of those checks, it is prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
a=int(input("Enter a number: "))
i=2
p=[]
while i<=a-1:
    p.append(a%i)
    i=i+1
if 0 not in list(p):
    print(a, "is a prime")
else:
    print(a, "is not a prime")
```